# Firebase write to file

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I want write a file with a button event in index.html.

I installed the node-module file-system:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "dependencies": {
  "file-system": "^2.2.2",
  "firebase-admin": "~4.2.1",
  "firebase-functions": "^0.5.7"
},
"private": true
}
```

And I tried these two ways of require

**index.js**

```
var functions = require('file-system');
var fs = require('fs');
```

And these two ways of write

```
var stream = fs.createWriteStream("./public/input.txt");
  stream.once('open', function(fd) {
  stream.write("My first row\n");
  stream.write("My second row\n");
  stream.end();
});

fs.writeFile ( './public/input.txt', 'My first text!', function (err) 
{
   if (err) {
       return console.error (err);
   }
});
```

But, it only deletes the contents of the input.txt.
Any better way to do this?

Comment: Why would you write to files when you can just upload them to your storage bucket? I have a strange feeling `fs` isn't supported in firebase cloud functions but could be completely wrong.

Comment: I'm doing an online code editor. And need generate and edit files and folders. Currently I use PHP for this. And I thought I could do this with Firebase. Because even the Google Apps Script generate files.

Comment: At the moment one solution is to save the codes in the database and use JSZip: https://stuk.github.io/jszip/